# Parent view error when installing Ecommerce without price odoo module

Tags: odoo-9

I have Odoo v9 installed in CentOS7 on a remote server.  I copied the Ecommerce Catalog without price module folder to the addons folder, activated developer mode, updated module list, clicked on install that module.  I get this error posted below and if I come back to the apps that module shows up as "Installing".

```
Error details:Element '<xpath expr="//del[@class='text-danger mr8']">' cannot be located in parent view


Error context:View `Suggested Products Without Catalog Price`[view_id: 924, xml_id: n/a, model: n/a, parent_id: 894]None" while parsing None:23, near<data inherit_id="website_sale.cart_lines" name="Suggested Products Without Catalog Price"> <xpath expr="//del[@class='text-danger mr8']" position="replace"> <field name="text-danger" invisible="1" nolabel="1"/> </xpath> </data>
```

Here is the xml view it refers to:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <template id="products_item" inherit_id="website_sale.products_item" name="Shop Without Catalog Price">
            <xpath expr="//del[@class='text-danger mr8']" position="replace">
                <field name="text-danger" invisible="1" nolabel="1"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>

        <template id="cart" inherit_id="website_sale.cart_lines" name="Shopping Cart Without Catalog Price">
            <xpath expr="//del[@t-field='line.product_id.lst_price']" position="replace">
                <field name="text-danger" invisible="1" nolabel="1"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>

        <template id="product_price" inherit_id="website_sale.product_price" name="Product Page Without Catalog Price">
            <xpath expr="//span[@class='text-danger oe_default_price']" position="replace">
                <field name="text-danger oe_default_price" invisible="1" nolabel="1"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>

        <template id="suggested_products_list" inherit_id="website_sale.cart_lines" name="Suggested Products Without Catalog Price">
            <xpath expr="//del[@class='text-danger mr8']" position="replace">
                <field name="text-danger" invisible="1" nolabel="1"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>

        <template id="modal_cart" inherit_id="website_sale_options.modal" name="Modal Cart Without Catalog Price">
            <xpath expr="//span[@t-attf-class='text-danger oe_default_price']" position="replace">
                <field name="text_danger oe_default_price" invisible="1" nolabel="1"/>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//span[@class='text-danger oe_optional']" position="replace">
                <field name="text-danger oe_optional" invisible="1" nolabel="1"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is going on here is that basically a `ViewB` tries to add something on `ViewA` using the `//del[@class='text-danger mr8']` xpath as a hook. But this element on ViewA has probably been removed by another module. So, what you can do here is find which view uses this xpath expression and either edit it to use another expression or find the `ViewA` that this expression refers to and add the `class='text-danger mr8'` element so that ViewB can operate normally.

Comment: Thanks but the mr8 label is there

Comment: How can I debug this and find the missing view?